# How to use the cookie of one API to another and run the chain of API calls in Java using the REST assured library

Tags: api, cookies, session-cookies, rest-assured

I am developing a program using the REST assured library in Java to automated the Webservice API testing.

Take an example of API chaining for the below scenario from an ecommerce site:

1.A user is logged in via a API Call named "LOGIN" for which the response body is "Login successfull"

2. Now the cookies values is fetched from the response body of the API call using the getdetailedcookies function.
3. The cookies which is received from the Login scenario is now given as an cookie header to another API call named as "CART"
4. The API response of the "CART" will contain details of the products present in the cart for the user logged in
5. The getdetailedcookie fetched from the "CART" API call should have some cookie which should be matched the usersession obtained from the previous API calls

NOTE:

1.All the API calls are given in TESTNG as different methods and run collectively

2.Each of the response is obtained properly when the cookie is given from the Website

Answer (score 0):

Refer below link , i think it has what you are looking for :

```
https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCookieStore/getCookies
```

Answer (score 0):

Use object of CookieFilter provided by restAssured and pass it in the filter.

```java
CookieFilter cookie = new CookieFilter();

public void sampleAPI(){
            RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost:8080";
            String response = given().contentType("application/json").accept("application/json").body(***).log().all().filter(cookie).when().post("/resource/Path")
                    .then().log().all().extract().response().asString();
        }
```

then use it in same fashion to the subsequent api call to which you want to pass the cookie and same goes for session also.
For session use SessionFilter.